# How to send C++ and mysql dynamic mysql queries

Tags: c++, mysql

Working with Visual Studio, Windows 7 and mysql.h library.

What I want to do is send a MySQL query like this:

```
mysql_query(conn, "SELECT pass FROM users WHERE name='Leo Tolstoy'");
```

The only thing I can't get working is sending a query where the name would be not a constant as it's shown above, but a variable taken from a text field or anything else. So how should I work with a variable instead of a constant?

Hope I made my question clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a prepared statement, which lets you parameterize values, similar to how functions let you parameterize variables in statement blocks. If using [MySQL Connector/C++](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp.html):

```
// use std::unique_ptr, boost::shared_ptr, or whatever is most appropriate for RAII
// Connector/C++ requires boost, so 
std::unique_ptr<sql::Connection> db;
std::unique_ptr<sql::PreparedStatement> getPassword
std::unique_ptr<sql::ResultSet> result;
std::string name = "Nikolai Gogol";
std::string password;

...

getPassword = db->prepareStatement("SELECT pass FROM users WHERE name=? LIMIT 1");

getPassword->setString(1, name);
result = getPassword->execute();
if (result->first()) {
    password = result->getString("pass");
} else {
    // no result
    ...
}

// smart pointers will handle deleting the sql::* instances
```

Create classes to handle database access and wrap that in a method, and the rest of the application doesn't even need to know that a database is being used.

If you really want to use the old C API for some reason:

```
MYSQL *mysql;
...

const my_bool yes=1, no=0;
const char* getPassStmt = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=? LIMIT 1";
MYSQL_STMT *getPassword;
MYSQL_BIND getPassParams;
MYSQL_BIND result;

std::string name = "Nikolai Gogol";
std::string password;

if (! (getPassword = mysql_stmt_init(mysql))) {
    // error: couldn't allocate space for statement
    ...
}
if (mysql_stmt_prepare(getPassword, getPassStmt, strlen(getPassStmt))) {
    /* error preparing statement; handle error and 
       return early or throw an exception. RAII would make
       this easier.
    */
    ...
} else {
    unsigned long nameLength = name.size();
    memset(&getPassParams, 0, sizeof(getPassParams));
    getPassParams.buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
    getPassParams.buffer = (char*) name.c_str();
    getPassParams.length = &nameLength;

    if (mysql_stmt_bind_param(getPassword, &getPassParams)) {
        /* error binding param */
        ...
    } else if (mysql_stmt_execute(getPassword)) {
        /* error executing query */
        ...
    } else {
        // for mysql_stmt_num_rows()
        mysql_stmt_store_result(getPassword);
        if (mysql_stmt_num_rows(getPassword)) {
            unsigned long passwordLength=0;
            memset(&result, 0, sizeof(result));
            result.length = &passwordLength;
            mysql_stmt_bind_result(getPassword, &result);

            mysql_stmt_fetch(getPassword);
            if (passwordLength > 0) {
                result.buffer = new char[passwordLength+1];
                memset(result.buffer, 0, passwordLength+1);
                result.buffer_length = passwordLength+1;
                if (mysql_stmt_fetch_column(getPassword, &result, 0, 0)) {
                    ...
                } else {
                    password = static_cast<const char*>(result.buffer);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // no result
            cerr << "No user '" << name << "' found." << endl;
        }
    }
    mysql_stmt_free_result(getPassword);
}
mysql_stmt_close(getPassword);

mysql_close(mysql);
```

As you see, Connector/C++ is simpler. It's also less error prone; I probably made more mistakes using the C API than Connector/C++.

See also:

- [Developing Database Applications Using MySQL Connector/C++](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html)
- [Connector C++](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Connector_C++) in the MySQL Forge wiki

Comment: sql::PreparedStatement  *prep_stmt  = con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test(id, label) VALUES (?, ?)");

Comment: @user60627: it's not clear what you mean. Did you have something to add to the answer? Are you requesting a clarification?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just build the query-string, using sprint or concatenating strings or whatever, so that by the time it gets to MySQL, MySQL just sees the SQL and has no idea where the constant came from?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: You mean like this?
string querry = "SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE name='text i want to add'";

mysql_query(conn, querry);

After this I get following error:
error C2664: 'mysql_query' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::string' to 'const char *'

Comment: `mysql_query(conn, querry.c_str());`

Answer (score 0):

here is an example:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/// ...

string name_value = "Leo Tolstoy";

ostringstream strstr;
strstr << "SELECT pass FROM users WHERE name='" << name_value << "'";

string str = strstr.str();
mysql_query(conn, str.c_str());
```

Comment: It must be either война or мир :)

Comment: Am I missing something? I do like you showed here but I get following 2 errors:
 error C2065: 'str' : undeclared identifier
 error C2228: left of '.str' must have class/struct/union

I should use classes or what?

Comment: if you dont like ostringstream, you can make it simpler: string query = "SELECT pass FROM users WHERE name='" + name_value + "'"; mysql_query(conn, query.c_str());

Comment: Hmmm. Gives another error:
error C2664: 'mysql_query' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'const char *'

Happend to me when tried to format the string before and add string name as the argument instead of this line in query statment.

Comment: Do I have to use Dynamic connection with database server to use this? Or static is enough? Cause I get NULL :(

Comment: sorry once again, I suppose I have done to much programming today. I fixed my example above, strstr.str().c_str() is surely an easy way to core dump.

Comment: Sorry for beeing so noobish, does it returns int value? Because when I do:
char answ[256];
answ = mysql_query(conn, str.c_str())
    ofstream fr("Result.txt");
fr << answ;

I get this:

cannot convert from 'int' to 'char [256]'

Comment: Thank you, you helped a lot, already sorted out everything :)

Comment: @EimantasKasperiūnas: be careful. Interpolating values directly into the statement can lead to injection attacks.

Comment: what other ways I should use to avoid that?