# c++ mysql query string parsing with quotes and variables

Tags: c++, mysql, string, c++11

I am trying to update a mysql database without using mysql connector class in c++. But I can't figure out how to add a long integer to a string that the query will accept.

```
#define CONVERSION  16
    long myCounter   = 0 ;
    long gallons = 0;
    gallons = myCounter / CONVERSION;

    string sql = ("UPDATE utilityroom.Sprinklers SET "
        "gallons='@gallons' WHERE label='PUMP';");

    query_state = mysql_query(connection, sql);
    result = mysql_store_result(connection);
```

It keeps failing at the 2nd argument in the query.

error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int mysql_query(MYSQL*, const char*)’

EDIT:

I hate the way c++ handles strings. I don't understand why every string has to be converted to a class element!

Here is what I changed to get it working:

```
    #include <sstream>
    ostringstream strstr;
    strstr << "UPDATE utilityroom.Sprinklers SET gallons='" << gallons << "' WHERE label='PUMP';";
    string sql = strstr.str();
    query_state = mysql_query(connection, sql.c_str());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
query_state = mysql_query(connection, sql.c_str());
```

There is no implicit cast from std::string to const char*.

Comment: Thank you. Where can I find more information about declaring a string with the ".c_str()"

Comment: For example here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str

Comment: It now compiles correctly but the variable is being passed incorrectly. it is passing "@gallons" instead of the value.

sql= UPDATE utilityroom.Sprinklers SET gallons='@gallons' WHERE label='PUMP';

Comment: You can not use the @gallons syntax in C++ like that. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649454/how-to-send-c-and-mysql-dynamic-mysql-queries, but be aware of the SQL injection problem and use prepareStatement as the second answer suggests.

Comment: is there any way of adding the variable to a string without converting it to a class element? I have tried all the examples in the link you provided and they all fail with various errors during compile.

Comment: I think it is working, Seems like I am going around the block to go across the street, but it is updating the database now. I had to add the following.
  #include <sstream>
  ostringstream strstr;
  strstr << "UPDATE utilityroom.Sprinklers SET gallons='" << gallons << "' WHERE label='PUMP';";
  string sql = strstr.str();

Comment: Really read about SQL injection! Otherwise, I do not want to stand below a sprinkler controlled by your code!