# Safe from sql injection queries/statements in MySQL connector/C++

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, sql-injection

So, im afraid of my databases being attacked using sql injection. I know, that in php/etc the way to prevent theese is parametrized queries/prepared statements. But i cant find anything that would work like parametrized queries in this backend.

So what is the best way to safely execute queries/statements?

Comment: This any help to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/8649713/2310830

Comment: The first hit on Google for "mysql connector c++ prepared statements" is straight from the [mysql-connector documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html

Comment: @Botje Yes, i know about this one. Aka prepared statements. But, i cant find parametrized queries, not the statements. And, if you read carefully, you can see that i stated, that i cant find only parametrized queries. Afaik prepared statements cant work like queries.

Comment: Nevermind, theese work as queries.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah! Thats exactly it. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send C++ and mysql dynamic mysql queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649454/how-to-send-c-and-mysql-dynamic-mysql-queries)

Comment: @ИгровойканалArtemPLaYs Example 2 in the same page clearly shows that it works for SELECTs as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, prepared statements can be also used as queries.

Thanks to @RiggsFolly for linking a code sample proving this.

Comment: Right, you can use a parameter in any type of SQL statement, in a place where you would use a constant value like a quoted string or date constant, or a numeric constant.

Comment: I treat "SQL statement" and "SQL query" as synonyms. Some SQL statements (e.g. SELECT or SHOW) have result sets, some SQL statements (e.g. INSERT or CREATE) do not have result sets.